# Michael hartl Chapter 11 Mailer test error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to learn ruby on rails by following the tutorial of Michal hartl.
But still a learning student trying to pick it up fast.
But i'm stuck at chapter 11 on a specific part that is "Mailer test".

it gave me the following failure:

```
FAIL["test_account_activation", UserMailerTest, 0.8010926319984719]
 test_account_activation#UserMailerTest (0.80s)
        Expected /Michael\ Example/ to match # encoding: US-ASCII
        "\r\n----==_mimepart_5811b80d754fe_7347fb30ec66649\r\nContent-Type: text/plain;\r\n charset=UTF-8\r\nContent-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\r\n\r\nUser#account_activation\r\n\r\n, find me in app/views/user_mailer/account_activation.text.erb\r\n\r\n\r\n----==_mimepart_5811b80d754fe_7347fb30ec66649\r\nContent-Type: text/html;\r\n charset=UTF-8\r\nContent-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\r\n\r\n<!DOCTYPE html>\r\n<html>\r\n  <head>\r\n    <meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=utf-8\" />\r\n    <style>\r\n      /* Email styles need to be inline */\r\n    </style>\r\n  </head>\r\n\r\n  <body>\r\n    <h1>User#account_activation</h1>\r\n\r\n<p>\r\n  , find me in app/views/user_mailer/account_activation.html.erb\r\n</p>\r\n\r\n  </body>\r\n</html>\r\n\r\n----==_mimepart_5811b80d754fe_7347fb30ec66649--\r\n".
        test/mailers/user_mailer_test.rb:12:in `block in <class:UserMailerTest>'
```

here is my user_mailer_test.rb

```
require 'test_helper'

class UserMailerTest < ActionMailer::TestCase

  test "account_activation" do
    user = users(:michael)
    user.activation_token = User.new_token
    mail = UserMailer.account_activation(user)
    assert_equal "Account activation", mail.subject
    assert_equal [user.email], mail.to
    assert_equal ["noreply@example.com"], mail.from
    assert_match user.name,               mail.body.encoded
    assert_match user.activation_token,   mail.body.encoded
    assert_match CGI.escape(user.email),  mail.body.encoded
  end
end
```

hope someone can help and explain me why it failed?

thanks alot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it already fixed.
There were some map structure mistakes.
Pretty noobish mistake hahaha.